Delphi, XML Databinding wizard and "Interface not supported" error
After using Delphi 12 "XML Data Binding" with xsd file, I tried to load the XML file, but I got "Interface not supported" error.
This is the whole xsd file content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://www.easa.europa.eu/erules-export" elementFormDefault="qualified"
  xmlns="http://www.easa.europa.eu/erules-export">
  <!--
    EASA eRules XML Export 1.0.0 - Schema Definition
    June 2022
  -->
  <xs:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"/>
  <xs:element name="document" type="document-type"/>

  <xs:complexType name="document-type">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="frontmatter" type="frontback-type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="toc" type="toc-type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element name="backmatter" type="frontback-type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="document-metadata"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="topic-metadata"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="frontback-type">
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="sdt"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="toc-type">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0">
      <xs:element name="toc" type="toc-type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="heading" type="heading-type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="topic" type="topic-type" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>      
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="topic-type">
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="sdt"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="title"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="topic-metadata"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="heading-type">
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="sdt"/>
    <xs:attribute name="title" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  
  <xs:attributeGroup name="topic-metadata">
    <xs:attribute name="ERulesId" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Domain" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="ActivityType" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="AircraftCategory" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="AircraftUse" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="AmendedBy" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="ApplicabilityDate" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="EntryIntoForceDate" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="EquivalentForeignRegulation" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="ICAOReference" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Keywords" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="RegistryState" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="RegulatedEntity" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="RegulatorySource" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="RegulatorySubject" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="TechnicalSubjectMatter" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="TypeOfContent" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="ParentIR" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="EASACategory" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="sdt">
    <xs:attribute name="sdt-id" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="document-metadata">
    <xs:attribute name="guid" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="pub-time" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="map-url" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="pub-template-url" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="xslt-url" type="xs:string"/>
    <xs:attribute name="source-title" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

  <xs:attributeGroup name="title">
    <xs:attribute name="source-title" type="xs:string"/>
  </xs:attributeGroup>

</xs:schema>

Here is the beginning of the XML file (link to whole XML):
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?>
<pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage">
    <pkg:part pkg:name="/customXml/item1.xml" pkg:contentType="application/xml">
        <pkg:xmlData>
            <CoverPageProperties xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/coverPageProps">
                <PublishDate>2008</PublishDate>
                <Abstract/>
                <CompanyAddress/>
                <CompanyPhone/>
                <CompanyFax/>
                <CompanyEmail/>
            </CoverPageProperties>
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>
    <pkg:part pkg:name="/customXml/item2.xml" pkg:contentType="application/xml">
        <pkg:xmlData>
            <FormTemplates xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms">
                <Display>DocumentLibraryForm</Display>
                <Edit>DocumentLibraryForm</Edit>
                <New>DocumentLibraryForm</New>
            </FormTemplates>
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>
    <pkg:part pkg:name="/customXml/item3.xml" pkg:contentType="application/xml">
        <pkg:xmlData>
            <Sources SelectedStyle="\APA.XSL" StyleName="APA" xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography" xmlns:b="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/bibliography"/>
        </pkg:xmlData>
    </pkg:part>


{ Global Functions }

function Getdocument(Doc: IXMLDocument): IXMLDocumenttype;
begin
  Result := Doc.GetDocBinding('document', TXMLDocumenttype, TargetNamespace) as IXMLDocumenttype;
end;

function Loaddocument(const FileName: string): IXMLDocumenttype;
begin
  Result := LoadXMLDocument(FileName).GetDocBinding('document', TXMLDocumenttype, TargetNamespace) as IXMLDocumenttype;
end;

function Newdocument: IXMLDocumenttype;
begin
  Result := NewXMLDocument.GetDocBinding('document', TXMLDocumenttype, TargetNamespace) as IXMLDocumenttype;
end;

This is the way I try loading the file.
function TXML_Reader_Main_Form.Read_XML( Const Fn:string): Boolean;
Var EASA_Doc: IXMLDocumenttype;
begin
     Result:=False;
     if NOT FileExists(SYS_Base_Folder+fn)
       then Exit;
     //
     EASA_Doc:=Loaddocument(SYS_Base_Folder+fn);
     //
     // more code ....
end;

"document" appears to be element name, but it fails.
I also tried "package", "pkg" unsuccessfully.
What I am missing?
Thank you.
Giovanni
